# Stuck on binarysearchtree implementation *Java*

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am doing my assignment and my last question asks me to write a program that uses binary search tree of characters. **You will read in a sequence of characters from input,
representing a preorder traversal of a binary search tree. You need to restore the original shape of the binary search tree from
this sequence and print the out the tree's content both in sideways (as illustrated below) and in an inorder fashion.**

Ipublic class PrintSideways {

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    if(args.length == 0 || args[0].length() == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("This is an invalid argument");
    }




    String chars = args[0];

    BinarySearchTree<StringItem, String> bst = new BinarySearchTree<StringItem, String>();
```

This is the skeleton code I received and I added the exception line to it. I am not really sure on how to start this code because I am weak on binarysearchtrees. Specifically, I don't get how to use the StringItem method in the parameter. This is the StringItem method provided.

```
public class StringItem extends KeyedItem<String> {    

  public StringItem(String str) {    
    super(str);    
  }    
  public String toString(){    
   return getKey()+"";    
}    
}  // end StringItem
```

Some detailed explanation would be much appreciated :) Thank you.

Comment: i am sure you will find some good example if google it

Comment: I just finished coding Infix to Postfix converter/calculator and got to this question. One thing I really don't get is printing the tree as a sideways output. How would I do that..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick implementation in C# but you would still need to tweak it to meet the needs of your structures. You should still get the idea of the algorithm or if you have trouble I can try to explain:

```
    private BinaryTreeNode<int> ReconstructPreorderRecursive(List<int> inorder, List<int> preorder, int inorderStart, int inorderEnd)
    {
        BinaryTreeNode<int> root = new BinaryTreeNode<int>();

        root.Value = preorder[preorderIndex];

        int index = inorder.IndexOf(preorder[preorderIndex]);
        //left subtree
        if (index > inorderStart)
        {
            preorderIndex++;
            root.LeftChild = ReconstructPreorderRecursive(inorder, preorder, inorderStart, index - 1);
            if (root.LeftChild != null)
                root.LeftChild.Parent = root;

        }

        //right subtree
        if (index < inorderEnd)
        {
            preorderIndex++;
            root.RightChild = ReconstructPreorderRecursive(inorder, preorder, index + 1, inorderEnd);
            if (root.RightChild != null)
                root.RightChild.Parent = root;

        }





        return root;
    }
```

Usage:

```
    newTree.Root = ReconstructPreorderRecursive(lstInorder, lstPreorder, 0, lstInorder.Count - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :). But I think I will give up on this question as I don't have much time left. I will need to restart from the basics of binary trees.